# Magento2 run custom javascript after page load and all other scripts are finished

Tags: magento2, javascript

Is there any way to execute a custom javascript file after full content of the page is finished loading and after every other javascript file has finished execution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no, because the scripts are loaded asynchronously.

Comment: ok, can you please tell me, why this require(["jquery","domReady!"], function($){
 function removeUnused(elements) {
  $.setTimeout(function(){
   $(elements).each(function(){
    console.log(this);
    this.remove();
   })
  }, 5000);    
    }
 $(removeUnused('.page-actions, .action-select-wrap'));
}); fires $.setTImeout is not a function error ?

Comment: setTimeout doesn't jQuery Function, so you cannot use it as $.setTImeout , also It is spelled not properly

Comment: if are you talking about the capital I, that is not in the code..  nvm